# Euler's formula to show cost=(e^(it) +e^(-it))/2?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

hmm how do I show that cost=(e^(it) +e^(-it))/2 by the use of eulers formula? e^(it)=cost +isint ??
ty for help!

Comment: Just expand $e^{it} + e^{-it}$ and use the evenness / oddness of various functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$. Replacing $t$ by $-t$, we get $e^{-it} = \cos(t) - i \sin(t)$. Adding both, we get
$$e^{it} + e^{-it} = 2 \cos(t) \implies \cos(t) = \dfrac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}2$$

Comment: Said more succinctly: $e^{\pm it}=\cos t \pm i\sin t$; average 'em.